# Setting Text on a Button in a Fragment from the FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

On my FragmentActivity, I can't get this to work, to bring the button variable from a fragment:

```
View v= myfragclassvar.getView();
Button b=(Button) v.findViewByid(R.id.button1);
b.setText("dddd");
```

Nullpointer to the v variable..

I'm trying to set the text in a button that is in a fragment, from the fragment activity...

Any help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling getView() on the fragment AFTER its onCreateView() has been called.

You can implement a callback method in your FragmentActivity to be called from your fragment's onCreateView() to pass the fragment view to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with fragments, you should have your view in like below :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}
```

I would recommend it to use `onViewCreated` to communicate with the view directly.